# Same technology for streaming video to iOS, Android app

Tags: android, ios, streaming, live-streaming

I would like to know the best way to stream video to an iOS and Android app.
I would like to use the same technology for all mobile operating system.

I think to use the HTTP Streaming Live because this is the only protocol supported by IOS.
But I do not know if the HLS works on Android, Blackberry and Windows Phone.

If I use the HTTP Live Streaming, I do not need to use a streaming server like Wowza or DSS, right?

Regards

Aleanar

Answer (score 1):

the android tablet versions (3.0+) only supports HTTP Live Streaming, but (nearly) all versions support rtsp streaming.

Answer (score 1):

HLS should be your protocol of choice although it is not supported by legacy handsets such as Nokia and Blackberry. If you are creating native applications it is possible to use third party players supporting HLS and embed that in your application.